# Oracle Error when creating a Table. ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I'm not exactly sure why I am getting this error message:
ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias
00998. 00000 -  "must name this expression with a column alias"

Here's my code:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table_volume1 AS (SELECT t.year,
      t.month,
      soldto,
      t.pickup,
      product_id,
      t.originfacilitycode,
      t.destinationfacilitycode,
      Sum(t.tot_weight),
      Sum(T.tot_billableweight),
      Sum(t.tot_postage),
      Sum(t.cnt_manfst),
      CASE
        WHEN t.markupreasoncode IN ( '20' ) THEN 'NQD'
        ELSE ''
      END AS markupreasoncode 
FROM   ops_owner.volume_summary_month t,
      ops_owner.track_mail_dsp_products a
WHERE  dateselect IN ( 202105 )
      AND t.dsp_id = 101
      AND t.manifesteddspproduct = a.dspproductcode
GROUP  BY t.year,
         t.month,
         soldto,
         t.pickup,
         product_id,
         t.originfacilitycode,
         t.destinationfacilitycode,
         CASE
           WHEN t.markupreasoncode IN ( '20' ) THEN 'NQD'
           ELSE ''
         END);'
```

Comment: What do you not understand?  All the columns in the table need to have names.

Comment: In addition to the other comments, your SELECT references two columns without an alias prefix to specify which table it comes from - soldto and product_id. To eliminate any confusion on the part of oracle, you, or anyone who follows you, if your SELECT has more than one table, then _all_ columns should be prefixed with the table alias.

Comment: Check this link https://www.plsql.co/ora-00998-must-name-this-expression-with-a-column-alias.html . If a GROUP BY function or other analytical functions are used then a Alias needs to be specified.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle can automatically generate names for most of the fields, but not for the SUM fields - you will have to supply aliases.

**Edit to complement this answer**

The columns:

```
  Sum(t.tot_weight),
  Sum(T.tot_billableweight),
  Sum(t.tot_postage),
  Sum(t.cnt_manfst),
```

Should have aliases, as in:

```
  Sum(t.tot_weight) as total_weight,
  Sum(T.tot_billableweight) as total_billable_weight,
  Sum(t.tot_postage) as total_postage,
  Sum(t.cnt_manfst) as total_cnt_manfst,
```

Comment: It cannot generate any names, it uses column names defined in query, i.e. all the columns used in query need to be addressable by name